# Track records update based on User entry

Tags: apex, soql, class, dml

I have a requirement to show five sections with different SOQL querry records. Now one common field in all of them is an input text PICKLIST field. While doing update I want to track only those records where User has changed picklist value runtime and update only those records without touching other records. Can someone suggest me a wayout.

Comment: make a trigger, use `Trigger.new` and `Trigger.old` and then compare them?

Comment: When you say "Show" Does than imply a VF?

Comment: HI Amit, yes it does

Comment: Hi Novarg, I need to do it in a apex controller

Comment: can you post screenshot of your VF with 5 section if thats possible. Is Picklist really input field on this VF?